# Dunford-Pettis-like theorem for $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

The Dunford-Pettis theorem states that a family $\mathcal F\subset L^1(\Omega)$ is relatively weakly compact if and only if $\sup_{\mathcal f\in F}||f||_1 <\infty$ and $\mathcal F$ is equi-integrable, i.e. for $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\int_A|f(x)|\,dx < \varepsilon
$$
for all $f\in \mathcal F$ whenever $|A|<\delta$.

> Is there a way to characterize **$p$-equi-integrability** of $\mathcal F\subset L^p(\Omega)$ in a similar manner? $p$-equi-integrability means that for $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
>   $$
> \int_A|f(x)|^p\,dx < \varepsilon
> $$
>   for all $f\in \mathcal F$ whenever $|A|<\delta$.

**Edit:** I am sorry if the question was worded poorly. What I want to characterize is $p$-equi-integrability, not weak compactness in $L^p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $1<p<\infty$, the spaces $L^p$ are reflexive. Hence, closed balls are weakly sequentially compact, and by Eberlein-Smulyan theorem weakly compact.

Weakly compact sets are bounded, thus contained in a closed ball, hence there is equivalence of both statements.

---

Here is an example that weak compactness does not imply $p$-equi-integrability. Define $f_n:=\chi_{(0,n^{-1})}n^{1/p}$. Then $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L^p(0,1)$. Its weak limit is zero, since equal to pointwise limit. However $(|f_n|^p)$ is bounded in $L^1(0,1)$, contains no weakly converging subsequence, hence it is not equi-integrable, and $(f_n)$ is not $p$-equi-integrable.

Comment: I am sorry but I fail to see how this is related to p-equi-integrability. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: By the way, did you mean to say that bounded sets are _relatively_ weakly compact?

Comment: @BigbearZzz rephrased the statement to be about closed balls

Comment: Still, am I correct that your post only mentioned about weak compactness but nothing on $p$-equi-integrability?

Comment: Added an example to show that weak compactness does not imply p-equi-integrability